# Relation of reproducibility and the lack of contigencies with the scientific method

Tags: epistemology, philosophy-of-science, philosophy-of-physics, scientific-method, quantum-physics

What is the relation of reproducibility and the lack of contigencies with the scientific method?

Quantum mechanics and Statistical physics/mechanics are vurnerable/suspectible to contigencies. We have Heisenberg's Princible to thank for that and the very nature of Statistical physics/mechanics.

Relativistic physics and Astrophysics are vurnerable to the lack of reproducibility. We have not experienced ourselves or produced relativistic speeds with our current technology and we can never attain the speed of light as long as the Lorentz Transform holds. We can only observe stars we cannot reproduce them.

Photonics then are vulnerable to both. We are dealing with particles for which the Heisenberg Principle holds that travel with the speed of light that we can only "attain" by producing photons and have not yet reached relativistic speeds in any other way.

Physics is the first thing that comes to mind when one thinks of science, scientific method and scientific theory.

Comment: If "contingencies" mean unpredictable events why "vulnerable"? They are not a threat, they are part of the order of things. Lack of direct reproducibility may indeed hinder development of predictive theories (as in economics or sociology), but not necessarily. Astronomy is one of the oldest and most precise predictive disciplines, despite complete experimental non-reproducibility. In the end, predictivity depends more on regularity of the phenomena themselves than on whether or not we can directly reproduce them.

Comment: @Conifold Predictivity is exactly that. Lack of Contigencies. Can we have probabilistic predictions under very restrictive conditions arising from the pure application of the scientific method? Klein Nishina distribution is exactly that. One has a probability distribution of the scattering angle of a photon. My question was not about predictivity in itself. It was whether or not Predictivity(Lack of Contigencies) and/or Reproducibility were decisive in order to decide if a discipline applies the scientific method purely or not.

Comment: Scientific method it is a loose collection of approaches that vary from discipline to discipline and change over time, there is no applying it "purely". In any case, predictivity and reproducibility depend on the nature of the subject the discipline studies, and that determines what its scientific method amounts to, not the other way around.

Comment: Is predictivity and reproducibility then a necessary condition for the pure application of the scientific method or not? That is what I am asking. Are predictivity and/or reproducibility necessary or somehow related to the method? Does physics lose its scientificity when it deals with Photons, Tachyons or Neutrinos? Because when it deals with them it loses its predictivity and reproducibility. And when dealing with the micro/subatomic world it loses its predictivity(unless we allow for predictions to amount to a probability distribution/ a probabilistic prediction like the ones economics make)

Comment: Like Conifold just said, there is **no such thing as a pure application of the scientific method**.

Comment: @BryanKrause, nothing essentially abstract can be materially applied, so saying that "there is no such thing as a pure application of the scientific method" is as worthless as saying "there is no pure visualization of a word."

Comment: @BryanKrause I am taking this expession from the WP article on Hard and Soft Sciences. What I want to transmit is absolute adherence and 0 diversion from the scientific method without any admixtures(impurities).

Comment: @user96931 It sounds like you are agreeing with me rather than disagreeing, and yet have chosen to present that as disagreement.

Comment: @GeorgeNtoulos If you are basing a question on something written someplace, you need to *cite it*.

Comment: @user96931 It does not seem to be self-evident to the OP, who first brought up "pure" application of the scientific method, and to whom my comment was directed.

Comment: @BryanKrause but I am not basing my expression on the Wikipedia Article. It is not a premise. I simply liked "applying a purer form of the scientific method". So I am using something that I think is similar.

Comment: @BryanKrause **Pure application of the scientific method** then was nothing more that a poor choice of words. Could you please suggest an alternative wording to express **absolute adherence and 0 diversion from the scientific method without any admixtures(impurities)**?

Comment: Absolute adherence and 0 divergence are even worse, one can not absolutely adhere to and 0 diverge from a shifty cloud. There is a sensibility, somewhat outdated, positivist philosophers of science used to have that physics should be "the model" of doing science, and some characteristics of its method Wikipedia lists were elevated to a paradigm. However, they are not universal even in physics, and Wikipedia says in the paragraph right after:"*Some philosophers and sociologists of science have questioned the relationship between these characteristics and perceived hardness or softness.*"

Comment: You seem to be missing the point. There is no ONE scientific method defined by [sufficiency and necessity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necessity_and_sufficiency). This philosophy of science issue is known as the [demarcation problem of science]. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demarcation_problem). The words 'pure' and 'real'  are [weasal words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weasel_word).

Comment: Psycholinguistics gives us the notion of [prototype theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype_theory) inspired from Wittengenstein's [family resemblance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Family_resemblance). This problem goes back at least to Ancient Greece and [featherless bipeds](https://www.laphamsquarterly.org/animals/miscellany/plato-and-diogenes-debate-featherless-bipeds). Questions of criteria such as reproducibility are heavily dependent on the science in question. In physics, it's a must, but in sociology where complexity rules, less so.

Comment: @JD Would the lack of contigencies make a field unscientific according to your answer in: Why is the explanation of physical phenomena not deductive? Is experimental reproducibility irrelevant to the scientificity? Why is Astrophysics a science if it completely lacks experimental reproducibility if experimental reproducibility is necessary?